# Is it possible to remap the pan function in node editors? Middle Mouse -> Right Click

Tags: node-editor, keymap

I didn't see this in the keymap. I'm thinking it's hardcoded and haven't found an addon that'll do it either.

I use a few other applications that all use right click to pan the node graph so I'd like to complete the consistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command I was looking for was actually under View2D instead of the node editor section.
[image]